# Returning PHP array to Javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays, canvas

I am trying to return my SQL query array into a javascript array and then display the info one at a time. I have found a few helpful posts already on here but I still cannot get it to work. I am new to ajax and so please forgive any stupid mistakes. Below is the php followed by a description.
php: this is in an external file from index.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM photos";
$queryresult = mysql_query($query);

while ( $line = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $path[] = $row[0];
}
$paths = json_encode($path);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $paths;
?>
```

This gets the results (they are file paths) array and json encodes them to pass to javascript. Connection.php is correct and it is working.

HTML/Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="JavaScript/gjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function imageload(){
var i = 1;
$.getJSON('phpfiles/getpiccode.php', function(data) {

    var can = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

    $.each(data,function(idx, row){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        can.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1280, 800);
    }
    img.src = row;
            i++;
});

});

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<canvas id="canvas" class="canvas-one" width="1280" height="800">
<script>imageload();</script>This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas</canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope that makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: var newpath = "<?=$paths ?>"; inside the change handler.. that really looks messed up..

Comment: I got that from another post on this site. I do not know if it is correct, but have tried many other ways and nothing else seems to work. Open to ideas. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have updated my javascript using all the suggestions to hopefully explain it better. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `json_encode()` to encode it as JSON.
In recent browsers you can simply turn the string from that function into a JavaScript object using `var obj = JSON.parse(yourstring);` - but better use e.g. jQuery for AJAX and JSON parsing.

Update: Your JavaScript should looke like that to iterate over the data from your query:

```
$.getJSON('phpfiles/getpiccode.php', function(data) {
    // get canvas object. it's the same for all images so only do it once
    var can = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    // iterate over the elements in data
    $.each(data, function(idx, row) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            can.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1280, 800);
        }
        img.src = row;
    });
});
```

However, it might not do what you want: It will draw all images pretty much at once at the same position.

Also replace `<script>imageload()    </script>` (assuming that's the function containing your JavaScript) with `<script type="text/javascript">imageload();</script>` as that's the correct/proper syntax.

In your PHP code you'll have to replace `return $paths;` with `echo $paths;` unless you are using some framework which relies on your file returning something. Additionally it'd be good to send a JSON header: `header('Content-type: application/json');`

PS: `SELECT *` combined with `MYSQL_NUM` is a BadThing. It relies on the columns in the table having a certain order. If you just need one column use "SELECT columnName"; if you need all, use `MYSQL_ASSOC` to get an associative array.

Comment: I agree. I also think that jQuery could make the stated intent (an incremental image display) much easier in other ways. And I'm curious why the new `canvas` is necessary, unless this is going to be expanded upon?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought I was using JSON in my PHP. I did not know it could be parsed though. I will try that. I am just starting to learn jquery, but I tend to default to what I know, I will try to update the code with jquery if I can. I chose canvas simply because it seemed easy and is new. I am not stuck to it though.

Comment: Using canvas for drawing-related stuff is perfectly fine and actually a good thing. jQuery just helps you with AJAX and DOM manipulations in case you need some. --> jQuery and canvas are for completely different things.

Comment: I am aware that they are different, I just cannot get them to work. I encode the php array using json_encode(), but do I need to decode it? How do I pass to, and then read that encoded array in javascript? Thanks for the replies.

Comment: JSON is a subset of JavaScript. So you could do something like `var obj = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;` When using AJAX you need to use eval or JSON.parse (or let e.g. jQuery do that for you)

Comment: I have updated my javascript using all the suggestions to hopefully explain it better. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: Your javascript code is pretty bad. Check my answer in a few moments for the correct way.

Comment: Thank you again for the help. I made the changes you recommended (edited above), but I still cannot get it to work. I have a few questions though. What is idx in you .each line? Index? Also when I run it through the Chrome debugger, it does not even seem to enter the function. Thanks again.

Comment: If it doesn't enter the function, add console.log(data); before the each "loop" to see what you actually received. idx is the element number - not really needed but the element itself is passed as the second parameter so you need a first one, too.

Comment: I tried that but it does not get the the loop. It stops at the $.getJSON line and just skips out of the function. It also does not seem to run imageload(); in the canvas. I don't see what is wrong. This is very confusing. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!